# In France, does a foreign citizen have to be a registered student in order to be an intern?

Tags: internship

[This site](https://www.prospects.ac.uk/jobs-and-work-experience/working-abroad/work-in-france) states that foreigners in France may only be interns if they are students. Is this accurate? And if so, how is "student" defined?

Comment: It may not be accurate. It is just a private party writing something on the internet without any accountability. I am not from the UK. I am not intending to be an intern. Translation of birth certificate is irrelevant to the question. There are laws in France governing all interns, for example the minimum that an employer is obliged to pay them, and I was hoping someone at this website might know whether it is true or not true that all foreign interns in France must be students, what that means if true, and whether it is part true. "Find out for yourself" is a rather disappointing answer.

Comment: @ruffle : I have many links (all about France and french laws), and it's quite easy to find out on the public government-driven websites: [internship](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F16734) and [companies](https://www.service-public.fr/professionnels-entreprises/vosdroits/F20559). I don't know if it deserves a full answer though...

Comment: The answer to the first question is either "yes" or "no". I'd welcome any properly sourced answer that tells me which it is. I'm not saying an answer is something I "deserve". I'm aware this is a private company's website. Please - no more comments; either an answer that includes the word "yes" or the word "no", or a deletion because the question is considered detrimental to the company. One or the other.

Comment: @ruffle : it was the "*small*" amount of data in my comment (links only?) that triggered the "*I don't know if it deserves a full answer though*", not your OP ;) and you can also add the fact that it's not en English (the links / data), so I questioned myself, and not the legitimacy of your Q

Comment: @OldPadawan - Ah, OK, no problem! Your comment might have been clearer if you'd said "provides enough material for" rather than "deserves". Many thanks for the links. I'm still unclear on the main question, though. Certainly some sites say an intern has to be a student, but there are also some internship offers that don't stipulate this requirement when the employer or agency would easily have been able to choose this option before posting. Apologies if my question sounded a bit spur-of-the-moment, but I've read a fair bit about French internships and still haven't found a reliable answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:** yes  you need to be a student

**Long answer:**
Internship ("stage" or "stage en entreprise") in France is a specific type of contract only intended for student as part of their studies. So it does not matters if your are a foreigner or french, you need to be a student.

Since it is part of your studies the contract ("convention de stage") need to be signed by you, the entreprise and your school/university. Your school need to ensure your internship subject is relevant to the diploma you prepare.

All these information can be found [in french](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F16734)

As for how a student is defined, I guess anyone registered in a school/university.